# Can't wirte getView in my SimpleAdapter in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, simpleadapter, getview

I have a fragment with a AsyncTask in which I do a parsing Json. To put every element in a list I use a `SimpleAdapter`. In my item list I have a button. Of course, if I want click on the button I need to create a getView. Well not works. This is the `SimpleAdapter` part inside the AsyncTask

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_rom_item, 
                  new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SURNAME }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.surname});
```

Now, after that, I tried to put this:

```
                 @Override
                 public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                 {
                     View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                      Button b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.mytask);
                      b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View arg0) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                     });
                     return v;
                 }
```

I get an error in `@Override` like: `The annotation @Override is disallowed for this location` and then of course in `getView()` syntax.. I don't know why. I tried also to clean the project but nothing. Is there any other solution maybe? Thanks.

Comment: where exactly have you placed this getView() method?
Can you post bigger part of your code?

Comment: argh it's a long code..mmh in `onPostExecute` method however.. just before the adapter i do the `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();` then the adapter and then the getView. Just after the adapter statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override getView() method when instantiating your adapter.
After that, you will not be able to do that.

Try this way:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_rom_item, 
                  new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SURNAME }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.surname}) {
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        return v;
    }
}
```